# How to split the data with splitting value?

Tags: perl

How to split the data using by particular letter but the splitting data is present into the previous split ted line.

My perl code

```
$data ="abccddaabcdebb";
@split = split('b',"$data");
foreach (@split){
    print "$_\n";
}
```

In this code gives the outputs but i expected outputs is:

```
ab
ccddaab
cdeb
b
```

How can i do this

Answer (score 3):

You can use lookbehind to keep the `b`:

```
$data ="abccddaabcdebb";
@split = split(/(?<=b)/, $data);    
foreach (@split){
    print "$_\n";
}
```

will print out

```
ab
ccddaab
cdeb
b
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need positive look behind if you want to include letter `b` as delimiter is excluded from resulting list.

```
my $data ="abccddaabcdebb";
my @split = split(/(?<=b)/, $data);
foreach (@split) {
    print "$_\n";
}
```

From `perldoc -f split`

> Anything in EXPR that matches PATTERN is taken to be a separator that separates the EXPR into substrings (called "fields") that do not include the separator.

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter of `split` defines what separates the elements you want to extract. `b` doesn't separate your elements you want since it's actually part of what you want.

You could specify the split after `b` using

```
my @parts = split /(?<=b)/, $s;
```

You could also use

```
my @parts = $s =~ /[^b]*b/g;
```

---

Side note:

```
split /(?<=b)/
```

splits

```
a b c b b
```

at three spots

```
a b|c b|b|
```

so it results in four strings

1. `ab`
2. `cb`
3. `b`
4. Empty string

Fortunately, `split` removes trailing blank strings from its result by default, so it results in the three desired strings instead.

1. `ab`
2. `cb`
3. `b`